# Create a hollow rectangle on c#

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am new at programming, I am trying to create a hollow rectangle using *, what I have done yet was a full rectangle. Still I am trying to develop a hollow one.
Any idea of what I've done wrong??

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int length, width;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the length of the hollow rectangle:");
            length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the width of the hollow rectangle:");
            width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 || i == length - 1 || j == 0 || j == width - 1)
                     Console.WriteLine("*");
                    else
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }              
            }
                Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It's an exercise in logical thinking.  Using a debugger, step through your code line by line as it executes.  Where does it first do something that you want to modify?  What information do you have available to you at that time when you want to modify the behavior?  What logic can you write in the code which would examine that information and conditionally perform different behavior?

Comment: Step through the code while it runs with the debugger to see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

**Debugging**

As the commentators have stated, the most common way to handle this situation is to step through the debugger and see what is going on. This works and is very valuable, you should/will learn how to do this with time.

**Readability**

I would like to make an argument for how much the readability of your code can help you avoid and find bugs (and help you develop algorithms in this case).

**Naming**

Yes, improving the naming and readability of your code helps improve the approach-ability of problems with your code.

Let's start with `i` and `j` and `length` and `width`. Which one is which? It's not easy to immediately know now is it?

How about we use `width` and `height` and `x` and `y`? If you've ever taken a math class, you now know which is which immediately. That's always a plus.

```
var width = 10;
var height = 10;

for (var x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    for (var y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {

    }
}
```

So immediately this part of the code makes more sense to us. Now let's get to the innards.

**Break-down Conditions**

`i == 0 || i == length - 1 || j == 0 || j == width - 1` This bit of code is going to have to be double checked time and time again. You're going to question if you missed something and as a beginner you might forget what you intended it to do (happens to the best of us sometimes).

Variables to the rescue!

```
var isFirstRow = x == 0;
var isLastRow = x == width - 1;
var isFirstColumn = y == 0;
var isLastColumn = y == height - 1;
var isBorderPosition = isFirstRow || isLastRow || isFirstColumn || isLastColumn;
```

These variables are pretty clearly named now right? Now you know that your goal is to track if you're on a border of the rectangle and how you are determining whether you are there or not.

**Bug Finding & Logic**

Seems a bit more obvious what the problem is now right? If you're on a border position you print an asterisk **otherwise** print a **new line**.

```
if (isBorderPosition)
    Console.WriteLine("*");
else
    Console.WriteLine("\n");
```

This will just product a line of asterisks won't it? You want spaces in there somewhere don't you? What about the following?

```
if (isBorderPosition)
{
    Console.Write("*");
}
else
{
    Console.Write(" ");
}

if (isLastColumn)
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
}
```

This works, but hold on a second. Aren't rectangles enclosed? So we're only ever going to have a new line when we've just printed an asterisk.

```
if (isBorderPosition)
{
    Console.Write("*");
    if (isLastColumn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
else
{
    Console.Write(" ");
}
```

**Bring it together**

```
var width = 10;
var height = 10;

for (var x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    for (var y = 0; y < height; ++y)
    {
        var isFirstRow = x == 0;
        var isLastRow = x == width - 1;
        var isFirstColumn = y == 0;
        var isLastColumn = y == height - 1;
        var isBorderPosition = isFirstRow || isLastRow || isFirstColumn || isLastColumn;

        if (isBorderPosition)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
            if (isLastColumn)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Just plug in your code for retrieving `width` and `height` and you should be good to go. I hope this helps you better handle some bugs in the future, or at the very least, makes you aware of how much code-readability can help.

**Note**

I did have a bug at one point when writing this and I used the debugger to step-through and help me realize where I went wrong (I had the `isLastColumn` if-statement as an else-if-statement so it was just printing horizontal lines of asterisks instead of vertical ones, hehe).

Comment: Using var for known types? Like nails on a chalkboard to me.

Comment: var isn't dynamic. Var just tells the compiler to figure it out because chances are you know it already. e.g. `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()` instead you could do `var ms = new MemoryStream()` Doesn't affect runtime at all. Compiles to the same code.

Comment: I know what a var is, and in this case it's lazy.

Comment: I like uniformity, it's not laziness. To be frank, calling someone's coding style lazy just because you don't agree with it seems a bit rude.